Wrong Hebrew text direction in SodaPDF
I have a problem in SodaPDF free version when I try to type in Hebrew (written from right to left) - the text it is written in the opposite direction. I tried adding text both in edit mode and not in it. It sometimes notifies me that "the font is not embedded on my system", and I tried to use many different Hebrew fonts, as it seems to be suggesting the fonts I can access on control panel.
Thanks for your help!

According to an official response to a community discussion post in 2020:

"...the current version of Soda PDF does not support right-to-left languages...   ...we have already flagged this feature... ...to implement it in future updates."

Given the age of the response, it may be useful to reach out to Soda's support team for a status update.
